# QT Designer для Mac Os

Tags: qt, macos

Добрый день, не подскажете существует ли сабж? Я изучаю питон и не получается работать с QtCreator... так как там надо знать С++

Comment: существует. Но смысл? когда и QtCreator норм QtPy держит)))

Comment: посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226730/where-is-qt-designer-app-on-mac-anaconda